# AddressSanitizer throwing SEGV on unknown address C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I have a task where I have to make a class depending on `std::multiset`. The idea is that it gets 2 multisets in its constructor, they then have to be sorted and put back in those variables while the class is in scope.
To provide an example:

```cpp
std::multiset<int> a;
std::multiset<int> b;
a.insert(4); a.insert(3); a.insert(1); a.insert(10); // a={1,3,4,10}
b.insert(3); b.insert(2); // b={2,3}

if(true){
    multisets_merge_view<int>(a,b); 
    // sorts them and makes it, so that:
    // a={1,2,3,3}
    // b={4,10}
}
// and here, the multisets need to go back to their original state:
// a={1,3,4,10}
// b={2,3}
```

We have to work with `g++` 9.3.0 under Ubuntu 20.04, with the following flags: `-fsanitize=address,leak,undefined -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror`
The code - that was given and I cannot touch - to check if everything works correctly:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include "msmview.h"
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "msmview.h"

struct string_size_less
{

  bool operator()( const std::string& lhs,
                   const std::string& rhs ) const
  {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
  }

};

const int max = 1000;

bool check()
{
  std::multiset<int> a;
  std::multiset<int> b;
  a.insert( 1 );
  a.insert( 7 );
  a.insert( 4 );
  b.insert( 4 );
  b.insert( 3 );

  std::multiset<std::string> s;
  std::multiset<std::string> t;
  s.insert( "C++" );
  s.insert( "Pascal" );
  s.insert( "Haskell" );
  t.insert( "C" );
  t.insert( "Ada" );

  std::multiset<int> x;
  std::multiset<int> y;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < max; ++i )
  {
    x.insert( i );
    y.insert( i );
  }

  bool c = x.count( max / 3 ) == 2;
  if ( !c )
  {
    multisets_merge_view<int> mvi( a, b );
    multisets_merge_view<int> mvm( x, y );
    multisets_merge_view<std::string> mvs( s, t );

    c = x.count( max / 3 ) == 2 && 3 == s.size() &&
        0 == s.count( "Pascal" ) && 1 == t.count( "Pascal" ) &&
        0 == x.count( max - 1 ) && 1 == s.count( "C" ) &&
        0 == a.count( 7 ) && 0 == b.count( 3 );
  }
  if ( !c || 1 != x.count( max / 3 ) || 1 != s.count( "Pascal" ) ||
       0 != s.count( "C" ) || 2 != t.size() || 1 != x.count( max - 1 ) ||
       1 != a.count( 7 ) || 1 != b.count( 3 ) )
  {
    return false;
  }

  if ( c )
  {
    const multisets_merge_view<int> mvi( a, b );
    const multisets_merge_view<int> mvm( x, y );
    const multisets_merge_view<std::string> mvs( s, t );

    if ( 5 != mvi.size() || 2 != mvi.count( 4 ) || 0 != mvi.count( max ) ||
         5 != mvs.size() || 1 != mvs.count( "C++" ) || 2 * max != mvm.size() ){
      return false;
         }
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "neither";
    return false;
  }

  std::multiset<int, std::greater<int> > ga;
  std::multiset<int, std::greater<int> > gb;

  ga.insert( 0 );
  ga.insert( max );
  gb.insert( max );

  std::multiset<std::string, string_size_less> sa;
  std::multiset<std::string, string_size_less> sb;

  sa.insert( "C++" );
  sa.insert( "Haskell" );
  sb.insert( "Ada" );
  sb.insert( "SQL" );
  sb.insert( "LISP" );
  if ( c )
  {
    const multisets_merge_view<std::string, string_size_less> mvs( sa, sb );
    const multisets_merge_view<int, std::greater<int> > mvi( ga, gb );
    return 2 == sa.count( "C++" ) && 1 == sb.count( "C++" ) && 1 == gb.count( 0 ) &&
           3U == sb.size() && ga.size() == ga.count( max ) && 3 == mvi.size();
  }
  return false;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << "Your solution is " 
    << (check() ? "" : "not ")
    << "ready for submission."
    << std::endl;
}
```

And my code for the upper mentioned class:

```cpp
#ifndef MSMVIEW_H
#define MSMVIEW_H

#include <set>

template<typename T1, typename T2 = std::greater<T1>> 
class multisets_merge_view : public std::multiset<T1,T2>{
public:
    multisets_merge_view(std::multiset<T1> &a, std::multiset<T1> &b);
    multisets_merge_view(std::multiset<T1,T2> &a, std::multiset<T1,T2> &b);
    ~multisets_merge_view();
    int size() const { return _size; }
    int count(T1 t) const;

private:
    std::multiset<T1> *_apo;
    std::multiset<T1> *_bpo;
    std::multiset<T1,T2> *_apt;
    std::multiset<T1,T2> *_bpt;
    std::multiset<T1> _ao;
    std::multiset<T1> _bo;
    std::multiset<T1,T2> _at;
    std::multiset<T1,T2> _bt;
    unsigned int _size;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
multisets_merge_view<T1,T2>::multisets_merge_view(std::multiset<T1> &a, std::multiset<T1> &b):_ao(a),_bo(b),_size(a.size()+b.size()){
    _apo = &a;
    _bpo = &b;
    std::multiset<T1> tmp;
    tmp.insert(a.begin(),a.end());
    tmp.insert(b.begin(),b.end());
    a.clear();
    b.clear();
    for(typename std::multiset<T1>::const_iterator i(tmp.begin()),end(tmp.end()); i!=end; ++i){
        if(a.size() < _ao.size()){
            a.insert(*i);
        }else{
            b.insert(*i);
        }
    }
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
multisets_merge_view<T1,T2>::multisets_merge_view(std::multiset<T1,T2> &a, std::multiset<T1,T2> &b):_at(a),_bt(b),_size(a.size()+b.size()){
    _apt = &a;
    _bpt = &b;
    std::multiset<T1,T2> tmp;
    tmp.insert(a.begin(),a.end());
    tmp.insert(b.begin(),b.end());
    a.clear();
    b.clear();
    for(typename std::multiset<T1,T2>::const_iterator i(tmp.begin()),end(tmp.end()); i!=end; ++i){
        if(a.size() < _at.size()){
            a.insert(*i);
        }else{
            b.insert(*i);
        }
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
multisets_merge_view<T1,T2>::~multisets_merge_view(){
    if(_apo != nullptr && _bpo != nullptr){
        *_apo = _ao;
        *_bpo = _bo;
    }else if(_apt != nullptr && _bpt != nullptr){
        *_apt = _bt;
        *_bpt = _at;
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
int multisets_merge_view<T1,T2>::count(T1 t) const{
    int count = 0;
    if(_apo != nullptr && _bpo != nullptr){
        for(typename std::multiset<T1>::const_iterator i = _ao.begin(); i != _ao.end(); i++){
            if(*i==t) count++;
        }
        for(typename std::multiset<T1>::const_iterator i = _bo.begin(); i != _bo.end(); i++){
            if(*i==t) count++;
        }
    }else if(_apt != nullptr && _bpt != nullptr){
        for(typename std::multiset<T1,T2>::const_iterator i = _at.begin(); i != _at.end(); i++){
            if(*i==t) count++;
        }
        for(typename std::multiset<T1,T2>::const_iterator i = _bt.begin(); i != _bt.end(); i++){
            if(*i==t) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
};
#endif
```

When I run the compiler, AddressSanitizer throws a memory reallocation error found in `~multisets_merge_view()`, probably when `*_apt=_at; *_bpt=_bt;` happens (without providing a second template parameter in the main program, everything works fine, but as I said I can't modify that).
[image: console where error is shown]
Is there a way to fix this while not touching the main program and still using the `-fsanitize=address,leak,undefined`?

Comment: The destructor checks all four of `_apo`, `_bpo`, `_apt` and `_bpt` for `nullptr`. But each constructor only initializes two of them, leaving the other two uninitialized, containing random garbage.

Comment: You don't need two sets of everything in the first place. Realize that `std::multiset<int>` is merely a shorthand for `std::multiset<int, std::less<int>>`. If you give your `T2` parameter a default of `std::less<T1>`, then the comparator of your `multisets_merge_view` would always match that of the multisets passed to the constructor. You wouldn't need `multisets_merge_view(std::multiset<T1> &a, std::multiset<T1> &b);`, only `multisets_merge_view(std::multiset<T1,T2> &a, std::multiset<T1,T2> &b);`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for hours now, didn't realise that changing `std::greater<int>` to `std::less<int>` would make such a difference! Thank you again!